# How do I replace characters with special characters in "Case When Then" SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, replace, syntax, case, special-characters

I am replacing some data in my table using a CASE WHEN THEN statement. It works perfectly fine for cases like this one:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
    WHEN [Flight Number]            = '777777' 
    AND  [Passenger Surname]        = 'Horbache' THEN 'Horbaje'
    ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Passenger Surname], 'Ö', 'OE'),'Ü', 'UE'),'Ä', 'AE'), 'ß', 'SS'), '-', ''),' ','') 
    END AS [PASSENGER_SURNAME]
```

However, in some cases I have to replace my "normal" characters with some special character like an underscore. In such cases my statement is not working. I do not get an error, but it simply does not execute my change.

```
    SELECT
        CASE 
        WHEN [Flight Number]            = '777777' 
        AND  [Passenger Surname]        = 'Horbache' THEN 'Horba_e'  
        ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([Passenger Surname], 'Ö', 'OE'),'Ü', 'UE'),'Ä', 'AE'), 'ß', 'SS'), '-', ''),' ','') 
        END AS [PASSENGER_SURNAME]
```

Do you know how to make it work? I care about keeping this as a case statement as it is part of a bigger query and I do not want to change the logic. Am I simply missing something in the SQL syntax ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Which database are you using ? just ran SELECT CASE WHEN 'Horbache' = 'Horbache' THEN 'Horba_e' END test FROM dual; in oracle and it is working. 
If you say it executes without error which indicates the case condition evaluation might not happening as you expect.

Comment: I am using Microsft SQL Server Management Studio. I tried it for different cases and it works for all characters except the ones like " _, ‾, - "

Comment: There must be something else going on. Sql server doesn't care about the content of the string. Can you provide example data and a full query that reproduces the problem?